# Mid-bar brakes for only rear wheel?

Tags: brakes

I'm interested in adding mid-bar brakes to a [Salsa Vaya Deore](http://salsacycles.com/bikes/vaya/2017_vaya_deore). Is it advisable to add them only for the rear wheel (not both the front and rear wheels as is more common)? Are there clear downsides to doing this?

Comment: By mid bar brakes you mean cross/interrupter levers? And what are you worried about that you only want the back brake? Weight? Modulation? Bar space for accessories? The downside is that in an emergency situation you'd need to move back to the main levers or risk skidding out the back wheel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you were going to only add one set of cyclo/interrupter brakes to your drops, I'd add them to your **front** brakes:

- Front  brakes are more powerful and provide almost all of the braking force in emergency stops (i.e., you apply so much braking force you are almost in an endover situation).
- Rear brakes skid out more

So assuming your hands are on the tops of the bars when that car pulls out in front of you, you want the set of brakes that actually work to work when you squeeze them.

The cons are that if you're a newbie, the front brake is harder to modulate. The easy solution is to gain more skills in that area.

The other con is that [Americans inexplicably](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/brakturn.html) have the front brake on their left hand. You can easily (on many bikes) flip the handedness so that your dominant hand (usually right) controls the front brake. I flip all my brakes (right-rear) because I'm used to riding a motorcycle.

[image: Interrupter brakes]

p.s. This photo shows an interrupter on the right hand side going to the rear brakes.

Comment: your link is to this page. I assume you meant another page.

Comment: not just the americans, though. a lot of people have the front brake in the left hand.

Comment: Regarding which hand operates which brake, the late great Sheldon Brown's [theory about brake handedness](http://sheldonbrown.com/brakturn.html) was that the hand closest to the road is the hand used for signaling, and the other hand is used to operate the primary brake, but unfortunately the rear brake was assumed to be the primary.  That accounts for the standards in the US (left hand controls front brake) and countries where people drive on the left (right hand controls front brake).  The EU countries where people drive on the right, except Denmark, are apparently the exception.

Comment: @rclocher3 Except that the US is unusual in "officially" using just one hand to signal. In most countries, the signal for "I am turning" is to stick out the arm on the side you're turning on.